# What is the equivalent of impz() from matlab in python?

Tags: python, matlab

When I run this in matlab:

```
[num,den]=tfdata(Gz,'v');
impz(num,den,[0:13]);
```

I get a plot like this:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTz1i.png)

What would be the equivalent in Python? Does it even exist something like `impz()`?

Comment: Take a look at [scipy.signal.impulse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.impulse.html#scipy.signal.impulse).

Comment: And how could I get the impulse into a discrete plot? All I can get is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q07jU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs of [`scipy.signal.impulse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.impulse.html#scipy.signal.impulse):

```
>>> from scipy import signal
>>> system = ([1.0], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0])
>>> t, y = signal.impulse2(system)
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot(t, y)
```

To plot the points as a stem plot (discrete vertical lines instead of a line connecting the points) you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.stem`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html):

```
>>> plt.stem(t,y)
```

Comment: You have no idea for how long I've been looking for that, thank you very much. I'm from spain and I didn't know that was called a stem plot and for the query 'discrete plot python' I wasn't getting any help, thanks again!

Comment: This doesn't work for discrete-time systems

Comment: Nope, use `scipy.signal.dimpulse` for discrete time systems.